# how to bench mark / load test webserver with linux

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, benchmarking, lighttpd

are there any free resources that can effectively test my webservers? (1 lighttpd and 1 apache).
i have no linux based web server performance experience and cannot find any software for ubuntu.  i know fiddler exist for windows - maybe there is something like that for the opensource community?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/